# Why doesn't esbuild process exit when building by script?

Tags: exit, esbuild

I have this `build.ts` script:

```js
import * as esbuild from 'https://deno.land/x/esbuild@v0.19.0/mod.js'
await esbuild.build({
  entryPoints: ['main.ts'],
})
```

The command `deno run --allow-all --allow-env .\build.ts` runs fine, but it doesn't exit. Why is that?